# Searching a one-dimensional array for a particular value

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I'm a student and new to c#, I have tried to search an element and print index of the element,
but I don't know why it's doesn't work.

this is my code

```
string temp = " ";
int hold;
const int SIZE = 5;
int[] a = new int[SIZE];
bool found = false;
int num;
//reading num from user
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    a[i] = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Enter the array values: "));
}

// print values
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    temp = temp + a[i] + " ";
}
temp = temp + "\n";
MessageBox.Show("array values: \n" + temp);

// this part I want it
num = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Enter the value to found "));

for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
{
    if (a[j] == num)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Searched value found in array");
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Searched value not found in array");
```

and thank you

Comment: `else
                MessageBox.Show("Searched value not found in array");` a) That message box needs to be _after_ the loop. b) `Array.IndexOf` is likely better than your loop approach.

Comment: _for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)_ this is not correct. You should loop over the array.length to find the _num_ or just use SIZE as you do to get the inputs. With this code sometime you get the result and sometime you get errors or you don't find anything

Comment: like @Steve say it must be SIZE instead of num

Comment: like this? 
@mjwills

            num = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Enter the value to found "));

            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] == num)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Searched value found in array");
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Searched value not found in array");

Comment: Mpre or less, but you should stop the loop with _break_ if you find your number. And then you need something to not print the not found message if you have found it. Think about a _bool found = false;_ before initiating the loop. Set it to true if you find the value. At the end print the failure message only if you have not found the value

Comment: @Abdulkareem it is best to avoid code in comments but if you must put it in, use a single backtick ` at the start and end of each individual code line, like this: `code line 1;` `code line 2;`

Comment: @CaiusJard
Thank you for trying to help me, the code is working now.
 I am sorry because I put the code in the comment, it is my first question here.

Comment: @Abdulkareem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0#System_Array_IndexOf_System_Array_System_Object_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
    bool isFound = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
    {
        if (a[j] == num)
        {
            isFound = true;
        }
    }

    if(isFound) 
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Just finish it off..

Then consider how to stop the loop when you found what you want (efficiency: don't keep searching for something you already found)